# Functional inequation on $\mathbb{R}$: $f\left(x+y^2\right)-f(x)\geq y$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I have the following equation:

> $$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
> $$\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,\ f\left(x+y^2\right)-f(x)\geq y$$

$f$ is not necessarily differentiable/continuous/... (in fact, we can prove that it's not differentiable at all).

I need to prove if there are solutions, and if there are, I need to give one.

How would I do that?

What we have found so far:

- $f$ is not differentiable nor continuous anywhere (@nayrb and @rlartiga 's comments)
- $f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ (proof : @rlartiga 's comment)

Comment: You can show that any solution cannot be differentiable anywhere by dividing by $y^2$ and taking $y^2 \to 0$. So good luck there being a easy to find solution. My guess is no solution exists at all.

Comment: Letting $y^2 = x$, telescoping the inequality, and assuming continuity at $0$ with a value of zero you can show that $f(x) \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1} \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @nayrb The problem is that i can't assume continuity at 0 with a value of zero; the function might even be discontinous everywhere

Comment: fair enough, I'm just playing around at this point. Perhaps eventually one assumption we could make can be proven to be true.

Comment: @nayrb Anyway, is $f(x)\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\sqrt{x}$ a contradiction ? It seems okay to me

Comment: Don't think so. It's not clear to me that $f(x)$ must be increasing. What's the argument?

Comment: If you take any $z>0$  for $y=\sqrt{z}$ you have $f(x+z)-f(x)>\sqrt{z}$ so for all $z>0$ $f$ is not continous

Comment: Take $y=y_0>0$:

$$f(x+y_0^2)-f(x)\geq y_0>0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

So $f$ is strictly increasing

Comment: What sort of homework is this? Do you turn it in/has the due date passed? I think I got the solution--but I want to make sure everything is all set.

Comment: @nayrb it's a question my teacher gave me, i don't really have a time limit to solve it. However, i haven't managed to find the solution by myself, so i came here for help ;)

Comment: What sort of course? This is a fun problem!

Comment: @nayrb I'm french, so we don't have specific 'calculus' or 'topology' or whatever courses like there are in the UK/US. We have one general subject called 'mathematics', in which we see several parts of chapters (probabilities, groups theory, arithmetic, topology, ...) every year, and improve them the next year :)

Comment: Contrast the notation $y²$ with $y^2$.  On my screen they look different.  $\TeX$ was designed intelligently.  You can use it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh sorry, i've only started using Tex some days ago

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any $b>a$ and $n$, let $\Delta x = (b-a)/n$ and $x_{k} = a + k\Delta x$. Then

$$ f(b) - f(a) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x_k + \Delta x) - f(x_k) \geq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{\Delta x} = \sqrt{\smash[b]{(b-a)n}},$$

which diverges as $n\to\infty$, a contradiction! So there is no such a solution.

… and I think I'm late :(

Comment: How do you get $f(b)-f(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_k+\triangle x)-f(x_k)$ ?

Comment: +1 Nice (shorter) alternative answer. You got to let us low rep users have a chance anyways. =)

Comment: @Hippalectryon, you can check that it's just a telescoping sum.

Comment: @nayrb, Thanks for +1! :)

Answer (score 8):

Hint: Using $f(x+y^2) \geq f(x) + y$,

$$f \left(\frac{\pi^2}{6} \right)  = f \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \right) = f \left(\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} + 1 \right)\geq f \left(\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \right) + \sqrt{1}.$$
Similarly,
$$f \left(\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \right) = f \left(\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{n^2} \right)\geq f \left(\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} \right) + \frac{1}{n}.$$

Use induction to get a lower bound on $f(\pi^2/6)$ as a function of $n$. Finally, use $f(y^2) \geq f(0) + |y| \geq f(0)$ to get a contradiction. I can fill in more details if you are still stuck.

P.S. If you want to show $f(x)$ is undefined for any $x > 0$, use $x = c \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^2$ for the appropriate $c$ instead.

P.P.S. This answer can be generalized to show that no solutions exist for $f(x+y^p)-f(x) \geq y$ when $p>1$.

Comment: I understand that we therefore have $f(\pi^2/6)\geq 1+1/2+f(\sum_{k=n+1}^{\propto} 1/k^2)$. Therefore with $f(y^2)\geq f(x)+y\geq f(0)$ i get $f(\pi/\sqrt{6})\geq f(0)+\pi^2/6\geq f(0)$. What about it ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon, your statement isn't quite correct. You can write $f(\pi^2/6) \geq \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k + f(\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 1/k^2)$. Do you understand why? (Think induction.)

Comment: @nayrb I don't see where the sum on the 1/k comes from

Comment: @Hippalectryon If $a_n = f(\sum_{k=n}^\infty 1/k^2)$ then using the second big inequality in my answer you can iteratively show, or show as in a chain, that $f(\pi^2/6) = a_1 \geq a_2 + 1 \geq a_3 + 1 + 1/2 \geq a_4 + 1 + 1/2 + 1/3$ and in general, show that $a_1 \geq a_{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$. If it helps, note that the second big inequality can be written as $a_n \geq a_{n+1} + 1/n$.

Comment: @nayrb Now i understand your previous comment. How does that give us a contradiction ?

Comment: You can further show that $a_1 \geq f(0) + \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$ (look at the answer again). Finally, think about what happens when $n$ is very large. What happens to $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$? Have you learned about this sum before?

Comment: oh i think i got it - The sum if $1/k$ diverges, the sum of $1/k^2$ converges towards $l0$, therefore as f is strictly increasing, $f($sum of $1/k^2)> f(l0-1)$ and thus $\forall x \in\mathbb{R}^+, f(x)$ diverges ($\mathbb{R}^+$ to avoid any problem with square roots)

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^p$ converges for $p>1$. It doesn't matter what the value is, just that it converges. Hence one value of $f(x)$ cannot be properly defined. Notice my answer didn't use any properties of $\pi^2/6$.